# Can you create (or transfigure) plants with magic?

Tags: harry-potter

I'm asking because if you can create plants, you can indirectly create food. Such as turning a chair into an apple tree, or dandelions (which are edible).

Unless that means the dandelions either taste like a chair, or won't grow (or otherwise behave has dandelions should).

Comment: weve never seen them make anything other then flowers (which are "dead") we do have tons of examples of them enhancing plants to make them larger but never transfiguring something into a seed, or a living plant, or any plant type food.